# Kernel panic - ACPI ESXi 5.5 / 6.0 installer on HP ProLiant ML350p G8

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant

ESXi installer 5.5 / 6.0 fails to boot on HP ProLiant ML350p G8.
I get a kernel panic - ACPI.
ESXI installer paramters doesn't work:
apm=off acpi=off noapic
Disabling CPU c-states and changing to maximum performance profile doesn't help.
How is it possible to solve it?
[image: ESXi Kernel panic ACPI]

Comment: ESXi 5.5 is already EOL, 6.0 U3 will follow in march. Is there a particular reason why you are trying to install a server with such outdated software?

Comment: That's the latest version supported for this hardware: https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=server&productid=20215 The ESXi installation is a demand from the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution which worked was resetting the BIOS to defaults.
Not even disabling the [BIOS option processor power and utilization monitoring](https://serverfault.com/a/508873/212866).